# Polymorphism - Unsure about derrived class using templates - derrived function returns template type

Tags: c++, templates, boost, polymorphism, variant

Recently I've decided to work on a project where I need to have a single object, which can be any data type (uint8, unint16, uint32, or unint64) (I may like to add these are only numbers, and will only be +, -, *, /, <<, >>. I looked into Boost::variant, however after trying it out, I have been discouraged by it as I couldn't retrieve the data correctly. argh - applying visitors?? So I have looked at other methods to emulate this.

Below this point is experimentation, and seems wrong, very wrong:

(I'd like to say that I'm not too in-depth with polymorphism / inheritance, so sorry in advance)
I tried to create a base object, and then set the base object to a derived class - a derived template class which is the data type of my choice(uint8, uint16, uint32, or uint64) After, I can simply retrieve the data which I previously set using the method get():

```
DynamicVariable *a = new TypedDynamicVariable<unsigned int>(12345); 
std::cout << a->get() << std::endl; 
delete a;
```

or:

```
DynamicVariable *a = new TypedDynamicVariable<unsigned char>(255);
std::cout << a->get() << std::endl;
delete a;
```

representation example:

```
unsigned int  a = 100;
unsigned char b = 20;
std::cout << a + b << std::endl;
```

results in: error C2039: 'get' : is not a member of 'DynamicVariable'

I'm getting errors that a->get() doesn't exist in the BASE class. I searched online to find this code (dynamic_cast):

```
DynamicVariable *a = new TypedDynamicVariable<int>(12345);
TypedDynamicVariable<int>* p = dynamic_cast<TypedDynamicVariable<int>*>(a);
std::cout << p->get() << std::endl;
```

As you can see, this: TypedDynamicVariable**< int >** and dynamic_cast*>(a) (specifying that it's an INT) to me defeats the whole purpose of what I would like to be doing.

Below is the class that I have sort-of hacked together from many unsure hours of reading online. It seems to have the general outline of my ''solution'' however I DO know that there is important contents missing / needs improving apon, or in fact that polymorphism isn't what I want after all / cannot be used.

```
class DynamicVariable
{
    public:
        //constructor & virtual destructor
                 DynamicVariable() {}
        virtual ~DynamicVariable() {}

};

//unique data
template<typename T>
class TypedDynamicVariable : public DynamicVariable
{
    private:
        T _data;

    public:
        //constuctor
        TypedDynamicVariable    (const T& data) : _data(data) { }

        //prototypes
        void    set             (const T& data) { _data = data; }
        T       get             (void)          { return _data; }
};
```

If anyone could please help me understand whats wrong with the above class and guide me to a working solution, or point me in the right direction with boost::variant if they are truly what I was looking for after all.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the problem with Boost.Variant? also, have you checked Boost.Any?

Comment: hang on a minute - what problems did you have with `boost::variant`?

Comment: You cannot in general have a variable that "can be anything". If there are no constraints on your data, you cannot do anything meaningful with that data.

Comment: Well here is an example:


char c = 12;
boost::variant<char, int, float, double> var = c;

//displays value fine
std::cout << var << std::endl; 

//addition - doesnt work
var = var + 1; //proposing that the varant understands its a char (ie can be added / subtracted etc)
std::cout << var << std::endl;
`

Comment: you can't expect all operators to be overloaded for all types in a sensible way! If you want this sort of functionality, follow their guide and implement the necessary operator overloads!

Comment: By anything i DO mean - only an char, short, int, long   (integers / floats) - not strings or another data type. - Im only wanting to harvest this functionality for the data types being x bytes long. ie: a->get() = b->get() + a->get()  // this actually represents int + char

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
DynamicVariable *a = <some initialisation>
std::cout << a->get() << std::endl; 
delete a;
```

does not work, because the compiler must know how to call `a->get()` without knowing what derived type `a` actually points to. For this reason, only those members that are part of `a`'s declared (static) type are considered and `get` is not one of them.
This is the same problem that Boost.Variant and Boost.Any also face.

In the end, it boils all down to one simple thing: If you don't know what type of value is currently stored in a `boost::variant<>`/`boost::any`/`DynamicVariable`, then you can't get that value out.
For Boost.Variant, you retrieve the value with `boost::get<type>(variant)`. For Boost.Any, you retrieve the value with `boost::any_cast<type>(any)`. For `DynamicVariable` you will probably have to make something similar.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `boost::variant` if particular types are well known at compile time (you have to provide the list to instantiate it). and only **that** types can be stored in a variant.  then you may use visitors to do smth with stored data (see also `which()` member-function).

alternatively you may use `boost::any` w/o any limits on contained data types.

writing your own variant is (almost) impossible to implement in terms of traditional OOP: **cuz you need to write a `get()` member w/ different return type (unknown at compile time).** (which is impossible in C++).

and your current wrapper (mostly) useless in terms of polymorphism -- you can have a container of pointers to your base class, but unable to realize what stored inside... so you can't `get()` anything out from this storage w/ knowledge whats stored in it. you have to provide some methods to do this. and they must use RTTI somehow... so in terms of performance it will be far from perfect... better to use `boost::variant`

Answer (score 0):

To be able to call `get()` from the mother class `DynamicVariable`, you need this method to be defined there, as virtual (pure in your case). So the question is: what is the type that a `get()` method in `DynamicVariable` would return? Don't try to find a trick with templates, virtual methods cannot be template.

I'm not a big fan of boost::variant or boost::any (even if there are useful!), it's sometimes a too easy way to solve design problems.

As alternative, I would really think about the application that you have in mind (I guess that your example is simplified). Ask yourself the following question: have the different types returned a common meaning?

- If yes, then you should consider having inheritence for the returned type as well: the method `get()` returns a pointer on a mother class, say `GeneralReturnType` and the daughter implementations return pointers on classes that are derived from `GeneralReturnType`.
- If no, then you should simply not call `get()` from the `DynamicVariable` class: the different return type have no common meaning, so the `get()` method has a different meaning depending on the class `TypedDynamicVariable` considered. To call the `get()` method, you should therefore know which derived class you have (maybe polymorphism isn't what you want, indeed...).